# Create a single value array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

why is the following code showing `undefined`? Are we not allowed to create an array with a single value? Putting two values won't show this error. Is this a problem with Javascript?

```
<script>
var tech = new Array(21);
alert(tech[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: to understand what happens ,  `console.log(tech.valueOf());`  or  `console.log(tech.toString()); `

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`new Array(21)` creates an array with a length of 21. If you want to create a single-value array, consisting of a number, use square brackets, `[21]`:

```
var tech = [ 21 ];
alert(tech[0]);
```

If you want to dynamically fill an array, use the `.push` method:

```
var filler = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    filler.push(i); //Example, pushing 5 integers in an array
}
//Filler is now equivalent to: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When the Array constructor receives one parameter *`p`*, which is a positive number, an array will be created, consisting of *p* elements. This feature is can be used to repeat strings, for example:

```
var repeat = new Array(10);
repeat = repeat.join("To repeat"); //Repeat the string 9x
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The array doesn't contain any elements, rather it has a `length` property of that value. There is a difference: `a=Array(3); b=[1,2,3]; 1 in b === true; 1 in a === false`

Comment: @Rob W - but the thing is I am dynamically creating arrays in a loop, some are single valued, some are not. So whats the better way?

Comment: You're still incorrect after your edit. They are not initialised as `undefined`. They simply don't exist.

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh Use the `.push` method to fill the array. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

by **new Array(21)** you're actually creating an array with 21 elements in it.

If you want to create an array with single value '21', then it's:

```
var tech = [21];
alert(tech[0]);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create an Array with a value using [Array.of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

```js
let arr = Array.of(8)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

guys the answer was as simple as this:

```
<script>
var tech = new Array();
tech.push(21);
alert(tech[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest accepting the answer by @zvona as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above example defining an array called tech with 21 positions. You have to difine it like that

```
var tech = new Array('21');
alert(tech[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

can use **push** or use **brackets** notation , passing single value is like initialize length

```js
var tech = new Array();
tech.push(10);
console.log(tech[0]);
```

---

```js
var tech = new Array(5);
console.log(tech.length);  // length = 5
tech.push(10);  // will add as a 6th element i.e. a[5]
console.log(tech.length);   // length = 6
console.log(tech[0]);   // undefined 
console.log(tech[5]);  // 10
```

---

or the easy way

```js
var tech = [10];
console.log(tech[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
    var tech = new Array(); //create an empty array
    tech.push(21); //Append items to the array
    console.log(tech); // console array the array
```

Be careful to avoid this;
`var array = new Array(n)`, this creates an empty array of length n, then if you push; you will simply append the new item to the end of the array and the new array length will be `n+1` and your new array will look like this `array = [Empty*21,new item ]`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to create an array using the Array constructor and having **only one number** element can be by using the `fill` method:

```
new Array(1).fill(4)// [ 4 ]
```

It will fill all the elements of the constructed array with a static value (4 in our case).

*Note that fill() will only work in browsers with ES6 support.*