# Why isn't my array index displaying?

Tags: javascript

This seems so simple and I honestly can't see why this isn't working. Looked at other answers on here and mine still isn't working.

```
var randomArray = new Array();

randomArray[0] = 859;

alert(randomArray[0]);
```

How come nothing happens? It's probably an easy answer but I can't work it out.

Also, I'm trying to work out how to put a random number in the array so rather than putting 859 in index 0 lets say I want to put a random number between 1 and 20 in, so far I've got this but thats not working either

```
randomArray[1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
```

EDIT: the .toString on alert seemed to fix it, thanks guys, knew it would be something small!

Comment: Well have you checked the browser's developer console to see if any errors are  being reported?

Comment: When adding a new value to an array, try this: `randomArray[] = 834;` or whatever value you want

Comment: Why would you multiple by 3 if you want a number between 1 and 20? Your first example work on every modern browser I have tried IE8/Chrome/Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/2ceUj/show

Comment: No errors on safari :(. If I do randomArray[] = 834 does it put it at index 0? Or 834?
Danny - Yeah I was just demonstrating what code I'm using, ill change it to 20 before I forget! :)

Comment: The next available index (if you have one value in the array, the index will be 1, if there are 4 values in the array, it will be 4)

Comment: @DanielLisik that is a syntax error in JavaScript.

Comment: Your problem to the first part of your question is elsewhere.  Check the developer tools for errors as @Pointy suggested. Here in this fiddle, you can see that your code works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/69qUc/

Comment: What **exactly** does your `<script>` tag look like?

Comment: @user3119721 there's no possible way that your problem stemmed from the lack of a `.toString()` call. Absolutely no way.

Comment: The code should work as it is. "`nothing happens`" probably means your script is not executed: Is JS allowed in browser settings? If the snippet is in a function, have you invoked that function? Some other code before these lines causes an error? There must not be a `src` attribute in the `script` tag, which has inline code. If the script is from an external source, check the path is correct. Please add more context to your post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833806/create-a-single-value-array-in-javascript

Comment: It seems while I was at it I removed a function further down the line, if an error is flagged up in the script, does the entire script abort all processes?

Comment: Yes.  If the script can't compile, it won't run.

Comment: Oh right, thanks guys I've been using vb.NET for so long I've forgotten so much about js :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your javascript being referenced properly in a script tag with the correct type set?

```
<script type="text/javascript" ...> </script>
```

If not, it's fully possible your browser is simply ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, because your question doesn't contain enough information to know for sure, but make sure that your code is in a `<script>` block that looks like this:

```
<script>
  // your code
</script>
```

Get rid of any "type" or "language" attribute on the tag; they're not needed and they're a source of error. If the "type" value is mispelled, then the browser will completely ignore the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling .ToString() on your array property.

```
alert(randomArray[0].toString());
```

Comment: `alert` calls `toString` internally for you.

Comment: I know, but browsers are funny sometimes so I always specify when the content is not a string.

Comment: Browsers aren't "funny sometimes". These things work predictably.

Comment: There's still no harm in toString and that has fixed unexpected behavior for me in the past.

Comment: Plus it appears the asker has said that it worked. Go figure. EDIT I guess it was an error else where in his script.